# How to convert x, y, z coordiate data to geometry (vertex, face) in three.js?

Tags: three.js, geometry, ifc

I have sets of [x,y,z] coordinate data, which forms one space.

e.g.
(0,0,-3000),(1848,0,-3000),(1848,-5177,-3000),(0,-5177,-3000),
(0,0,0),(1848,0,0),(1848,-5177,0),(0,-5177,0)

I would like to render the space coordinates using three.js.
I'm trying to create a function which creates geometry object to render.
However, it seems quite tricky to set vertices and faces.

**Is there a simple way to render xyz coordinate to geometry in three.js?**

**Or is it possible to draw 2D shape(with x, z) and make it 3D(with z)?**
because for each geometries, it has even height as you see at the given coordinate example.

Comment: Do you have a list of faces?

Comment: No I only have the set of xyz coordinate data. I would like to make a function which creates faces.

Comment: There are several ways to generate faces from a vertex list. Is your vertex count a multiple of 3 ?

Comment: The set of coordinates should be vertices, but I couldn't figure out how to  generate triangles out of the coordinates.

Comment: A very simple way to do is to generate a face (a triangle) every 3 vertices (this requires to have a multiple of 3 vertices).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Do you have any idea how I should create a multiple of 3 vertices out of given coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Concept

To define geometry in 3D you need:

- Points in 3D space; and
- Information about how your points connect.

For an arbitrary shape, you need to specify *faces* which join 3 or more of your points.

*Alternatively*, if you make assumptions about your shape (for instance, from your example coordinates, it seems like you are drawing an upright box) you may only need to supply coordinates.

### Example

From your example above, your box seems to have:

height: 3000 ; width: 1848 ; depth:5177

which enables you to use:

```
geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1848 , 3000 , 5177 );
```

Side note: a box should have 8 vertices, not 10. You have included [0,0,-3000] and [0,0,0] twice.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have many sets of space data, it could also be other shapes (e.g. pentagon upright box or etc). The coordinates should form a room shape and the room shapes will form a building. Is there any way to draw polyline(using x, y values) and make it upright box with given z value(height)?

Comment: And, when I use BoxGeometry, could I give the center/location for the box?

Comment: This is where my knowledge of three.js reaches its limit, but logically you would either have to define the faces on the outside, or extrude a 2D shape upwards.

Check out the source code from [this page](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shapes.html), which includes many basic shapes:

Comment: Thank you so much. Helped me a lot!